# Conway's soldiers - C

Tags: c, function

I am doing an assignment which involves building a C code for Conway's Soldiers. Like this but smaller board https://www.cleverlearning.co.uk/blogs/blogConway.php
The bottom half of the board is filled with pegs or 'X' and the upper part empty or '.'. Pegs can move up, left or right. Would it be correct to check if the pegs can move by calling the below functions:

```
int can_move_up(int board[ROWS][COLUMNS])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
        for (j=0; j < COLUMNS; ++j) {
            if (board[i][j] != PEG) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (board[i][j] == PEG && board[i][j-2] == PEG) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}


int can_move_left(int board[ROWS][COLUMNS])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
        for (j=0; j < COLUMNS; ++j) {
            if (board[i][j] != PEG) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (board[i][j] == PEG && board[i-2][j] == PEG) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int can_move_right(int board[ROWS][COLUMNS])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
        for (j=0; j < COLUMNS; ++j) {
            if (board[i][j] != PEG) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (board[i][j] == PEG && board[i+2][j] == PEG) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You should use pointers to your array instead of copying them to the function.

Comment: What are your functions `can_move_left` etc doing?? They go through the whole board. Shouldn't they be called with a peg position and check if the peg can move?

Comment: @A.R.C. (and whoever gave this an upvote) _You should use pointers to your array instead of copying them to the function._ Huh? Arrays are never _copied to functions_. Regardless, whether writing `int board[ROWS][COLUMNS]` or `int (*board)[COLUMS]`, the C compiler will always do the same - decay arrays in function parameters to pointers.

Comment: @A.R.C. If in doubt then compare the outcome of [`int square(int board[N_ROWS][N_COLS])`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/kuZrwZ) and [`int square(int (*board)[N_COLS])`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/mxQFXr) - identical upto the least bit. ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone! Nearly got my code to work now :)